# Normalize an image returns --->OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, normalization

Below is a python code I've written in order to normalise an image and make it illuminance-invariance.
For each pixel of the image, the new pixel value should be `(R/sum,G/sum,B/sum)`, where `sum=R+G+B`.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 


img=cv2.imread(r'C:/Users/kjbaili/.spyder-py3/color_supression_RV/rub00.jpg')


print(img[200,200])
print(img[200,200,0])

def normalized(down):

    norm_img = np.zeros(down.shape, down.dtype)
    

    width,height,channels=down.shape
    
    for y in range(0,height):
        for x in range(0,width):
              sum=down[x,y,0]+down[x,y,1]+down[x,y,2]
             
              b=(down[x,y,0]/ sum)*255
              g=(down[x,y,1]/ sum)*255
              r=(down[x,y,2]/ sum)*255
            
            
              norm_img[x,y,0]= b
              norm_img[x,y,1]= g
              norm_img[x,y,2]= r
              
    return norm_img


image=normalized(img)


cv2.imshow('normalized',image)


cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer
```

Although, I've found similar answered questions related to this here, i couldn't project this to my problem as i don't know which value comes results an infinity.

Would be glad for some help

Thanks in Advance

Comment: 1) `sum` is a python keyword, don't use it as a variable. 2) what happens if your `sum` is 0?

Comment: Try 255.0 instead of 255

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It returns with infinity, although i didn't expect that because the image is being read properly@QuangHoang

Comment: Have tried it. Still no work @ParthShah

Comment: I checked the sum value. Yes you're write, it returns an inf. I also checked the value of r,b, and g they all unrealistic: g 433.0952274799347
                                             r 431.0714256763458
                                             b 457.745903134346 .  Please help. @QuangHoang

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) Find the first point in the execution where the state of the variables is not what it is supposed to be  & say what you expected & why--with justification from the language definition. (Debugging fundamental.) Don't just dump code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your access indices are switched.  You should be doing `down[y,x,0]` etc. not `down[x,y,0]`.  However, I suspect that you're not encountering any errors in accessing here because the image is square.  In addition, when you add three numbers together with limited precision in comparison to full floating-point precision, your values will overflow.  For example, adding `200 + 100 + 50` in unsigned 8-bit integer will result in `350 % 256 = 94`.  What is probably happening in your infinity result is that either you have completely black pixels so the normalisation results in a divide by 0 error, or the sum of three values overflows to give you a value of 0 to again give you this result.

What you can do is perform a sanity check to make sure that if the sum of the three channels is not equal to 0, then perform the normalisation.  In addition, you will want to change the precision so that it can handle higher values after summing.

In other words:

```py
def normalized(down):

    norm_img = np.zeros(down.shape, down.dtype)
    

    width,height,channels=down.shape
    
    for y in range(0,height):
        for x in range(0,width):
              sum=float(down[y,x,0])+float(down[y,x,1])+float(down[y,x,2])  # Change
              
              if sum > 0:  # Change
                  b=(down[y,x,0]/ sum)*255.0   # Change
                  g=(down[y,x,1]/ sum)*255.0
                  r=(down[y,x,2]/ sum)*255.0
            
                  norm_img[y,x,0]= b  # Should cast downwards automatically
                  norm_img[y,x,1]= g
                  norm_img[y,x,2]= r
              
    return norm_img
```

This of course is very inefficient as you are looping over individual pixels and not taking advantage of the vectorisation that embodies NumPy arrays.  Simply put, use [`numpy.sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) and sum along the third dimension, then divide every channel by the corresponding amount:

```py
def normalized(down):
    sum_img = np.sum(down.astype(np.float), axis=2)
    sum_img[sum_img == 0] = 1
    return (255 * (down.astype(np.float) / sum_img[...,None])).astype(down.dtype)
```

The first line calculates a 2D array where each location sums along the channel dimension to give you the sum of the RGB values per spatial location.  I've also promoted the type to floating-point to maintain precision when normalising.  Next, the intermediate check on the second line of code ensures that there's no divide by zero error so any pixels that are 0, we set to a sentinel value of 1 so that the division results in a 0 value.  After, we take the input image and divide each corresponding RGB pixel by the sum at the corresponding spatial location.  Note that I've employed broadcasting so that I've made the 2D sum array into a 3D array with a singleton third channel to allow the broadcasting to work properly.  Finally, I multiply by 255 as you've done in your previous version.  I also make sure that I cast the final result to the incoming type in the function.

To be a bit cleaner, you can simplify this more by using the `keepdims` argument of `numpy.sum` to maintain the singleton dimension after you sum in the third dimension.  This way it avoids the manual singleton dimension insertion:

```py
def normalized(down):
    sum_img = np.sum(down.astype(np.float), axis=2, keepdims=True)
    sum_img[sum_img == 0] = 1
    return (255 * (down.astype(np.float) / sum_img)).astype(down.dtype)
```

Comment: Would `255 * down` not overflow? I always have a hard time with this uint8 image nonsense. It's so much easier to just use floating-point data everywhere... :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo I would rather the data be normalised to [0-1] lol.  Aha, I need to change the type for `down` too.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi all. @rayryeng thanks for your help. You were right. The  access indices are switched. It works now except that it is very slow, so as you said inefficient. I've tried the vectorisation as you suggested. BUT it returns a black image. Could you please test your function on any image to see if it works. Maybe i'm missing something

Comment: Yup made a slight mistake. Try now.

Comment: @rayryeng would appreciate it if you could vote up the question as i'm facing the question-limit problem due to the fact that i'm new here:)